# a single-threaded .net application, when run it , why all cpu cores work for it?

Tags: multithreading

I have a single-threaded .net demo code, the code is simple as  below:

```
private static void ArrayCalc()
{[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    int[,] data = new int[10000, 10000];

    Random rd = new Random();

    double result = 0;
    for (int ai = 0; ai < 10000; ai++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                result += Math.Sqrt(rd.Next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it on my computer which the cpu is  a 4cores,8 threads, i surmise only one cpu core should work hard, and other cpus should be free, since the code snippe is single-threaded.

but actually, when I run it, all cpu cores work hard for it. please see the screenshot:
[image: cpu usage]

I also track the tthread, it as below:
[image: thread usage]

If I stop the demo applicaion, all cpu cores  are going to free:
[image: CPU free]

My question is, I don't know why all cpu cores work for a single-threaded code. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Your profiler's CPU sampling rate may be less than your computer's context-switching rate, in which case you'll see CPU usage reported on more cores concurrently, even though only 1 is active at a time. In VS's Diagnostics Tools window you can customize the sampling rate, so if you're using a low rate then that may explain it.

Comment: I see it, Win11 22H2, resource monitor graphs.  I haven't yet been impressed with its accuracy, for one I can't get Task Manager's "System Idle Process" to agree with "Processes".  Resource Monitor shows CPUs at 100% but overall processor usage at less than 30%.  Makes no sense whatsoever, assuming a bug in something so basic is a stretch, best to ask at superuser.com.  Don't forget to document your OS version and hardware details.